App installer activity not starting in android
I'm trying to launch app installer from my app via intent. Every thing is working expect the popup to install app is not showing. I have write down logs to configure the issue, but according to logs, installer should be shown, but actually it is not showing.
Below is my code.

private fun openDownloadedApk(context: Context) {
    val downloadedApk = File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
        "OneScreen_Launcher_12_Dev__1.1.4_.apk"
    )

    if (downloadedApk.exists()) {

        Log.d("Installation", "Downloaded Apk Founded")
        val contentUri = MyFileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.myfileprovider",
            downloadedApk
        )

        if (contentUri != null) {
            Log.d("Installation", "Starting APK installation via Intent")
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
                setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
            }
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

            try {
                Log.d("Installation", "Starting APK installation")
                context.startActivity(intent)
                Toast.makeText(context, "APK installation started successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
                Log.d("Installation", "APK installation started successfully")
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                Log.e("Installation", "Activity not found to handle the intent: ${e.message}")
            } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                Log.e(
                    "Installation",
                    "Security exception: User might not have granted permission to open file.",
                    e
                )
                // Inform user about permission requirement and guide them to settings
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("Installation", "Error opening downloaded APK: ${e.message}")
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Installation", "Failed to create content URI for downloaded APK")
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Download", "Downloaded APK not found")
    }
}


Below are my logs.
01:07:00.995 Installation             D  Downloaded Apk Founded
01:07:00.995 Installation             D  Starting APK installation via Intent
01:07:00.995 Installation             D  Starting APK installation
01:07:01.021 Installation             D  APK installation started successfully


Google recommends using PackageInstaller -- see https://commonsware.com/Q/pages/chap-pkg-001.html for some material of mine on how to use it.

Can you suggest what's not working in my code as this seems very easy?

There is no requirement for ACTION_VIEW to be supported for this. I also do not know if your app has permission to access that APK -- it feels like it was not downloaded by your app, and, if so, you have no rights to read it on modern versions of Android. Logcat might give you some more information, such as errors from the app that will be started by that Intent.
